# Can't get this conditional statement to adjust columns back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1. Having issues getting this to work.
2. The intent is on click event to have a  list with two columns switch to 1 column while hiding same level elements and on next click do the inverse. I specifically can't get the conditional statement for the columns to switch back to two columns on the second click.

   ```
   <script>
       var $col = 2;

       $(".pft-directory").click(function () {
           $(".pft-directory").toggle("fast");
           $(this).toggle("fast");

           if ($col > 1) {
               $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1").set.$col = 2;
           } else {
               $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2").set.$col = 1;
           }
       });
       </script>
   ```

   Code Update:

   ```
   <script>
   var col = 2

   $(".pft-directory").click(function() {
   $(".pft-directory").toggle("fast");
   $(this).toggle("fast");
   if (col > 1) {
       $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
       col = 1;
   } else {
       $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
       col = 2;
   }

   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: can you show your HTML too please? it's hard to know what's going on with only the JS provided - but for starters, you are toggling the same element twice on click `$(this).toggle('fast');` refers to the element clicked which is the same as the line above it

Comment: `.set.$col` isn't this wrong?

Comment: That is not a valid way to use `css()`. no clue what .set.$col would do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of chaining `.set.$col = 2;` after the css, try ending the line after css. Then on the next line say `$col = 1 or 2` I would also advise not to use the bling sign for variables not directly pertaining to jQuery collections and such. I also do not believe .set is a valid method available.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, you solved my issues.